# Install GRUB and root system in different devices

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2

I am installing Ubuntu on my desktop (it will be the only system, so no dual boot). I have a 256GB drive (sdb), where I want the root partition to be, and a 2TB drive (sda) for my /home dir.

Problem is Ubuntu fails to install GRUB on both sda and sdb. If I place the root on sda (which I don't want to do), then it works. If not then the installation fails.

In sda I added a boot partition (I am not sure exactly what to choose here) and a primary. What should I do?

Comment: Have you set your bios to boot sdb? If you install grub to sdb but the system is trying to boot sda it will not work. On the other hand if you install grub on sda and boot sda it will work just like you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, and here is an answer that perhaps can help others in the future. The problem is that I was booting with the installer USB stick as a legacy device with secure boot disabled. Once I enabled secure boot and booted from the USB stick as a UEFI device it worked just fine.

I installed Ubuntu and GRUB on sdb, and /home on sda.